# django render_to_response how to send special characters

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, render-to-response

I have a string which is to be displayed in an html file. Certain words (tagged as "spc") in the string need to be displayed in yellow background and larger font.

I was trying to send the string (called tdoc) to the html file using `render_to_response` method. I replaced the 'spc' tag in the string with a div tag.  Suppose, after replacement, part of the string is  `we would seldom be prepared to <div id="spcl">examine</div> every`. My django code looks like `render_to_response('a.html',{'taggeddoc':tdoc})`

In my css, I have following code

```
 #spcl {  
background-color: #FFFF00;  
font-size:15px;  
}
```

So, I should see the word **examine** in bold font and yellow background, but I don't see that. When I viewed the source of the rendered html, it has following substring `We would seldom be prepared to &lt;div id=&quot;spcl&quot;&gt;examine&lt;/div&gt; every` instead of the original string.

How can I make the word 'examine' and similar words display in the required way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) to prevent html escape:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

...

render_to_response('a.html', {'taggeddoc': mark_safe(tdoc)})
```

Or use [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) filter in template:

```
{{ taggeddoc|safe }}
```

Example:

```
>>> from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
>>> from django.template import Template, Context

# without mark_safe, safe
>>> print(Template('{{ taggeddoc }}').render(Context({'taggeddoc': '<div>hello</div>'})))
&lt;div&gt;hello&lt;/div&gt;

# mark_safe
>>> print(Template('{{ taggeddoc }}').render(Context({'taggeddoc': mark_safe('<div>hello</div>')})))
<div>hello</div>

# safe filter
>>> print(Template('{{ taggeddoc|safe }}').render(Context({'taggeddoc': '<div>hello</div>'})))
<div>hello</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, couldn't have wrote it better myself. Thats assuming, I could! :P